# How can I express Sqrt[2] as an element in the field Q(2^(1/4))?

Tags: finite-fields

If I input: `ToNumberField[Sqrt[2], 2^(1/4)]`

Mathematica returns: `AlgebraicNumber[Root[-2 + #1^4 &, 2], {0, 0, 1, 0}]`

How would I know which root of `x^4 - 2` Mathematica is referring to here? In this simple example it must mean either of the two real roots of `x^ - 2`.  But how would I know this otherwise. In other words, my question is what does the 2 in the returned expression mean?

Comment: It refers to a "canonical" numbering. Without getting into that, I'll point out that you can apply `N[]` to see a numeric approximation thereof.

Comment: …or apply `ToRadicals[]` to it to see the corresponding radical form.